# Passing complex type with collection parameters to Invoke in a Ria Service

Tags: .net, wcf-ria-services

I am running into a problem using an Invoke method of a Ria Service.

Specifically, on the silverlight side of things I am adding a collection of Entity objects to a Parent Entity Object.

The Collection is set up as an Association.

When I pass the parent object to the Invoke method the Collection to does not serialize and come through. In this case all the information is new and nothing is yet stored in the database so I don't have any primary keys for any of the entities.

Does anyone have any idea how to get a Complex object containing a collection to serialize to an Invoke method?